# Eventlistener on dynamically generated iframe content does not fire

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

I have a chrome extension that injects an iframe into a loaded page. The content of the iframe is programmatically generated. It includes a button to which a click event listener is added. But it does not always seem to fire. Most of the times it works, but one case in which it doesn't work is when the extension is freshly loaded (as in installed). Below is the gist of my code, do you see any issue?

content.js:

```
var frame = document.createElement("iframe");

frame.onload = function() {
    var doc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;

    var closeButton = doc.createElement("input");
    closeButton.type = "button";
    closeButton.value = "X";
    closeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.body.removeChild(frame);
    });

    doc.body.appendChild(closeButton);
};

document.body.appendChild(frame);
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "eventlistener-bug",
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "run_at": "document_idle",
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }],
    "permissions": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: Content scripts declared in manifest.json aren't automatically injected into existing open tabs when an extension is installed/updated. You need to do it manually, for example [Chrome extension content script re-injection after upgrade or install](//stackoverflow.com/a/11598753)

Comment: @wOxxOm The problem is __not__ that the content script is not loaded at all. Only the click event listener is not always working.

Comment: Does it happen only in FF? I know it has some weird timing issues with iframes which required me to append the iframe to document body first, then proceed with accessing its content in a setTimeout callback.

Comment: @wOxxOm No, actually currently I'm only observing it in Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm I created a minimal non-working chrome extension [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/107fe229ca97edd8bf7d630643f06097)

Comment: @Makyen done, and also updated the content.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, it looks like this is a bug in chrome. It has been reported and accepted: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=745771

A fix is planned for version 61.

Possible workarounds are re-adding the event listener, e.g. in a mouseover event handler for the iframe.